# Multi threading or Multi processing for opening pages in BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup

I have a program that opens a long list of web pages using beautifulsoup, and extracts data from it.

Obviously it's fairly slow since it has to wait for each one to complete. I'd like to make it retrieve more than one at a time to speed it up.

I know that multithreading in python is a lot of the times, slower than using a singlethread. 
What would be the best for this? Multithreading or creating multiprocessing?

Comment: It depends.  Most of the time, threads will be the right call for something like this, as usually the bottleneck for crawlers is network I/O.  If you do enough local processing that CPU throughput is a bottleneck though, multiprocessing will be beneficial.  It also makes a difference if there's non-trivial collation of the data you scrape in each thread.  Depending upon what you do with the data, you could end up basically serializing your workers anyway (if they all have to wait on a single pipe to the main process, for instance).

Comment: A Professor once said: first measure then optimize. Use Both and post the answer!

Answer (score 1):

thats one of the main reasons to use scrapy, scrapy is built on twisted library to make http calls asynchronous **without** using multi threading and multi processing

a good point to start from can be the excellent [scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)

it also worth noting that multi threading / processing is usually the right approach when doing heavy cpu computation in a multi core environment, but when it comes to parallel IO operations you better choose an asynchronous programming solution rather than having threads waiting in blocking operation for some IO to happen while holding systems resources.

Comment: I'm using 3.3 as far as I know, scrappy is 2.7 only?

Comment: you're right, not yet http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-work-with-python-3 but you can always create a virtualenv...